# Binary Search Tree to list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

I've been given a BST in haskell that is capable of adding, removing, lookup, findingMax, and removingMax. I have to make a function that converts the data to a list structure.

```
bstToList:: (BST k v) -> [String]
bstToList EmptyBST = ["hi"]
bstToList (BSTNode k v nl nr) = bstToList nl ++ bstToList nr
```

The reason I have EmptyBST = ["hi"] in there was to check what it was returning. When given an input of

```
bstToList (bstAdd 1 "Phil" (bstAdd 2 "Ip" EmptyBST))
```

returns a list of ["hi","hi","hi"] And I'm unclear as to why everything is returning the empty list. Assume that all functions other than bstToList is correct and working properly. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
bstToList (BSTNode k v nl nr) = bstToList nl ++ bstToList nr
```

doesn't use the value at the node, which is why you only ever get data from the EmptyBST bits.

You need

```
BstToList :: BST k v -> [v] 
bstToList EmptyBST = []
bstToList (BSTNode k v nl nr) = bstToList nl ++ [v] ++ bstToList nr
```

so that the value at this node is inserted *between* the values on the left and the right of it. (This is called an in order traversal.)

If you want to list both the keys and values you need

```
BstToList :: BST k v -> [(k,v)] 
bstToList EmptyBST = []
bstToList (BSTNode k v nl nr) = bstToList nl ++ [(k,v)] ++ bstToList nr
```

Notice the brackets around (k, v) - they turn two items into a pair. The same goes for the type signature. (The missing pair syntax is why you got a kind error.)

[k,v] can only work as data if k and v are the same type, and [k,v] can't work as a type.

Comment: This is excellent thank you! I never realized I wasn't showing any values for the results. I've attempted to list both the [k,v] as a return type instead and now it gives me an error: `Kind mis-match
Expected kind 'OpenKind', but '[k, v]' has kind '[*]'
In the type signature for 'bstToList':
  bstToList :: (BST k v) -> '[k, v]`

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been a wonderful help in making me understand! :D

Comment: @AndrewC You could halve your constant factor by avoiding the use of `++`.

Comment: @Jubobs You mean going via `([v] -> [v])` and using `leftBit . (v:) . rightBit`? I'm not sure the OP had the right zone of proximal development for optimisation.

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, that's what I meant. I just thought I'd mention it, but you're right: the OP probably wasn't there yet, at least at the time of asking.